# Manually select items after query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a list of data, in which I want to manually select items in excel.

If the list would be static, I would add a column in the sheet and write an 'x' for each item I want to manually select; at the end with a simple filter, I have my results in an easy way.

But if the list comes from a power query transformation and is put in an excel sheet, I cannot work this way. If I would, at the first data refresh, the added column would be lost.

How to manage it?

Comment: check [this post](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/)

Comment: Thanks. Should work, even if it looks very twisted... I was hoping for easier solution, but that's reality

Comment: Give it a shot. Come back and post a question if you get stucked